# Angular: Change firebase path after component has been created

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to change the firebase path base on input from the user without having to refresh the component. So, once the component would load with a path and retrieve the data but then when the user enters a value in the input field, the database path would change using this value and then retrieve the data base on the new path. I've tried this but it doesn't work:

```
ngOnChanges(changes : SimpleChanges){
    if(changes['this.databaseService.serviceData']) {
      this.routeSub =  this.route.params
    .subscribe(params => {
        this.uid = params.get('uid');
        this.snaps = this.db.list(`snap-test/${this.databaseService.serviceData}/${this.uid}`).valueChanges();            

    })

  }
}
```

`this.databaseService.serviceData` contains the value that would change based on the input. Any suggestions?